# Complicated SQL query need query structure

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that pulls a result set in the following format

```
    .       Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4
    Row1
    Row2
    Row3
    Row4
```

There will always be 4 rows returned from this query.

What I ultimately want to do is make another result set that looks like this:

```
    .       Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5 Header6
    Row1
    Row2
    Row3
    Row4
```

Where [Header5,Row1] is the return value of another query that takes [Header1,Row1] and [Header2,Row1] as parameters

[Header6,Row1] is the return value of a DIFFERENT query that takes [Header1,Row1] and [Header2,Row1] as parameters

I have the first table done fine, and I actually have the entire thing working using for loops in my application code.  However, I am migrating the application to a different framework where it would really help (and I believe be much more efficient) if I could do this in one query and I don't know where to start.  I am not looking for anyone to write a query, I just need to know the structure of the query that I should use here.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT
  x.h1 AS Header1,
  x.h2 AS Header2,
  x.h3 AS Header3,
  x.h4 AS Header4,
  (SELECT y.h5 FROM y WHERE something with x.h1) AS Header5,
  (SELECT z.h6 FROM z WHERE something with x.h1 and x.h2) AS Header6,
FROM
  x
```

The subqueries MUST return 0 or 1 result. The query will fail if any subquery returns more than 1 result.

Comment: Hey, thanks that was fast.  At first glance this seems like it would work.  The subqueries would always return 1.  I will give it a shot and come back with the update.  Thanks!

Comment: They will always return `1`? Then why do you need a Subquery? Then you could also use `SELECT x.h1 AS Header1, ..., 1 AS Header5, 1 AS Header6 FROM x`. This would ALWAYS insert `1` for Header5 and Header6. Or will it insert `1` or `null` based on some condition?

Comment: @BenjaminM: I believe "The subqueries would always return 1" was in reply to "The subqueries MUST return 0 or 1 result".